# why is thread not running with correct priority in linux

Tags: c, linux

I have following code, which changes priority of current thread. I passed 90 as parameter, yet it looks like thread is running with priority 19. I have:

- checked that ulimit -r is set to 99
- process is running as root

How do I know that process is running with priority 19. I executed following command. As you can see pri is 19. Also what is the difference between rtprio and pri? I am using 2.6 kernel from redhat enterprise linux ver 6.3. Since, this is not a real time linux, is this line valid in code `if(pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &param))` as i am setting scheduler to `SCHED_RR`

```
ps -p 10834 -o pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat

PID   TID CLS RTPRIO  NI PRI PSR %CPU STAT
10834 10834 TS       -   0  19   9 99.9 R+
```

```c
void changePriority(int tPriority)
{
    int  policy;
    struct sched_param param;

    pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &param);
    param.sched_priority = tPriority;
    if(pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &param))
            err_sys("error while setting thread priority to %d", tPriority);
}
```

Comment: what does sched_get_priority_max(sched_getscheduler()) return?

Comment: Is your program running with root privileges?

Comment: yes it is running as root

Comment: Have you tried just running it as RT at prio 1? Prio 90 is pretty insane...

Comment: @titus it is returning 0. Both sched_getscheduler(pid) and sched_get_priority_max are 0

Comment: I think you should try sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_RR), as the current policy is not SCHED_RR

Comment: You should try `pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), policy, &param)`, ie change the priority within the *same* policy

Comment: @titus  sched_get_priority_max(sched_getscheduler(SCHED_RR)) is still 0

Comment: `sched_getscheduler` takes pid as parameter not the policy, it's `sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_RR)` not `sched_get_priority_max(sched_getscheduler(pid))`, you want to find out the maximum priority for the new scheduling, not for the current one, which I believe is not SCHED_RR, as SCHED_RR should not be 0

Comment: @titus you are right. this time sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_RR) is 99

Comment: @ring0 it sounds like it wont help to increase priority in current policy, as i shown above, that for current policy, the sched_get_priority_max are 0.

Comment: [Linux does not support thread priorities.](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qthread.html)

Comment: @Steve-o: It does for real-time threads, as discussed currently.

Answer (score 1):

Referring `PRI` vs. `RTPRIO`, verbatim from the `man ps`:

> PRI     priority of the process. Higher number means lower priority
>
> ...
>
> RTPRIO  realtime priority.

---

`PRI` could be set using the `nice()` system call or the `nice`command line tool. `PRI` is the process' main thread's priority. For Linux this also sets the priority for the process' non real-time threads*.

From `man 1 nice`:

> Nicenesses range from -20 (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least favorable).

`Niceness` and `PRI` are synonyms.

**A real-time thread is a thread with a scheduling policy different from `SCHED_OTHER`, `SCHED_BATCH` and `SCHED_IDLE`, as there are: `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR`.*

---

`RTPRIO` and scheduling policy could be set via the functions mentioned in the OP.

The scheduling policy is guaranteed to provide at least 32 different levels. Use `sched_get_priority_min` and `sched_get_priority_max` to determine the implemented range.